# Debugging installed PWA from Android Play Store

Tags: debugging, google-play, progressive-web-apps

I have a Progressive Web App I've built and put in the Google Play Store. To update the app I have just been creating new builds and deploying them to my AWS EC2 which is what the resources load from.

However, I am running into an issue with my assets. I have been able to update the code in the EC2 and see that the changes have taken effect in the app. Unfortunately, I have the issue now where my assets are not loading on the app version but work on the URL version.

What is the correct way to debug this? I can debug the URL version with ADB and the browser inspector. I can't do it when I click through on the actual app icon.

**Any ideas on this?** I may be misunderstanding how these things are implemented but afaik its a native wrapper webview. I didn't think I would need to Re-Appify into a new APK...

Comment: Do the changes show on the installed version after the user uses the app a second time? After closing the first time.

Comment: So the process I have in showing changes is I actually just uninstall the app and then reinstall it. 

I'm wondering if "appifying" a PWA changes the assets directory... That's the main issue for me I'm encountering in both my PWA's. The assets URL 404s in the app version but not the url version.

Comment: Have you checked if the changes show on the second visit after the changes? That is the default behaviour for a PWA.

Comment: Okay yes it appears that the changes are reflected. I am still lost as to why one one of these PWA's it is telling me it is missing assets but in the browser version it works. How do you go about debugging / seeing the console logs for the installed app? Will I have to figure this out in Android Studio.

Comment: Well surprise surprise I was digging around and it appeared that the app version in the settings says "Powered by Firefox". Lo and behold it doesn't work on the desktop firefox version so it looks like I should be able to use the firefox browser to make some headway.